# Simple division not happening

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to calculate the appropriate height for a UITableViewCell and a UIImageView by using the following method that gets called:

```
-(void)ratioCalculator
{
picH = image.size.height;
picW = image.size.width;

NSLog(@"%d = width %d = height", picW, picH);
picRatio = (picW/picH);
NSLog(@"%F", picRatio);
imageViewH = (260/picRatio);
NSLog(@"%d int", imageViewH);

return;
}
```

The thing is, when it gets called, the `picRatio = (picW/picH);` doesn't seem to be happening as the console says this:

```
2012-11-18 21:56:48.787 Name[5374:c07] 640 = width 360 = height
2012-11-18 21:56:48.788 Name[5374:c07] 1.000000
2012-11-18 21:56:48.788 Name[5374:c07] 260 int
```

The 1.000000 is the float `picRatio` and the 260 is the `imageViewH`. Obviously this means the incorrect heights are used for both the UITableViewCell and the UIImageView which are calculated like this:

```
else {
        [self ratioCalculator];
        return (imageViewH + 20);
     }
```

and

```
- (void)showImage:(UIImage *)theImage
{
    self.imageView.image = theImage;
    self.imageView.hidden = NO;
    [self ratioCalculator];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 260, imageViewH);
    self.photoLabel.hidden = YES;
}
```

As stupid a question as this probably is, why isn't this simple division working? Again, sorry if this is a stupid question, but it has me stumped. I feel like I'm going slightly mad.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, 
Regards,
Mike

Comment: Where do you instantiate the `picRatio` object?  Is it set to a float datatype?  It appears that what may be happening is that the picRatio is being set as as int, so when you are doing your division, the extra decimal information is being truncated.

Comment: Use small %f in formats and use %0.2f for 2 decimal precisions where needed and avoid the use of integer on such calculations where you need precision. I dont think this is stupid, I have stumbled upon many such small things every once in a while.

Comment: Sly, yes picRatio is a float ivar. insane Yes, converting picH & picW to floats fixed the problem. Thank you both, as you both kind of said the same thing. Interesting how it doesn't work when dividing ints.

Comment: Actually, it worked perfectly when you were dividing ints.  It just didn't work the way you expected.

Comment: @HotLicks, Right so what should I be expecting when I divide ints into a float?

Comment: Well, you don't "divide ints into a float".  The division is either integer or float.  If both operands are int then the division is int.  If either operand is float then the division is float.  If either operand is double then the division is double.  Operands are "promoted" int->long->float->double until both operands are the same type, then the division (or addition or subtraction or multiplication) is performed with two operands of the same type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
picRatio = ((float)picW/(float)picH);
```

Objective-c needs the proper iVar type assignment before dividing.
When you divide 2 integers, the output isn't a float, but an integer.

So 640/360 = 1.777 and this is treated as an integer, so the decimal value is ignores, which gives you the 1, you are getting.

If you do what I wrote, will actually produce a float, and give you the 1.777 output.

Comment: i believe that casting just one of the values into float is also enough

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you posted it just as I posted mine. Since, no one else has posted an official answer, I'll mark yours as the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I had a huge problem back when I was a beginner at this in objective-c and took me quite a while why this was happening, as most other programming languages I was using before, never had this behavior, so I can understand your frustration :-)

Comment: @Lefteris -- Virtually all common programming languages have this behavior, starting with FORTRAN -- C, C++, Pascal, PL/1, Java.  Of the languages I've used only "typeless" ones like APL and BASIC didn't have the behavior (since you couldn't specify numeric type).

Answer (score 2):

What you are missing is to cast the integers to float in order to make a float division

```
picRatio = (picW/picH); // gives an int division if picW and picH are declared integers

picRatio = (float)(picW)/picH; // gives you a floating point division
```

Comment: It's important to note that "cast" associates more closely than division, so `(float)(picW)/picH` is really `((float)picW)/picH`.  If you changed it to `(float)(picW/picH)` then you'd get integer division and the result of 1.00 again.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one is posting an official answer, I thought I'd do so to help anyone in a similar position. The comments on my question put me on the right track, and after further investigations I discovered that the compiler calculates the output based on the types of the operands. Therefore, if all the operands are ints, it casts an int to the destination, regardless of if it's a float or not. Solution: make at least one of your operands a float.

Hope this helps anyone in a similar position.